# Pass TWIG Objects to Javascript (json_encode result is empty)

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a collection of items passed from my controller to my twig template called qualifications. I then loop through each object in the collection and print it to a row in the table. Every respective row has an "Edit" button, which should pass that object's values to a javascript function. Here is my code:

```
{%for qualification in qualifications%} 
    <tr id="qualification_{{qualification.id}}">
        <td>{{qualification.name}}</td>
        <td>{{qualification.saqaId}}</td>
        <td>{{qualification.qualificationType}}</td>
        <td>{%if (qualification.course is null) %} - {%else%} {{qualification.course.name}} {%endif%}</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td><a class="button btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="setForm({{qualification|json_encode(constant('JSON_PRETTY_PRINT'))}});">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
{%endfor%}
```

I am getting the information in the table row as expected, but when looking at the HTML on the Edit button I just see `onclick="setForm({});"`. I have tried with and without the raw, I have also tried `{{qualification|json_encode(constant('JSON_PRETTY_PRINT'))}}` but all return blank.

On a similar, but not related note. I have been having other issues with TWIG as well. `{{dump()}}` just loads a while and then gives a blank page with an unspecified 500 error.  have tried activating the twig debug in services.xml and config.yml with what documentation I could find, but to no avail. This, however is not my primary concern, my primary concern is json_encode returning an empty result.

And help or advice on this would be greatly appreciated as I have run into a wall.

Comment: Did you mean `json_decode`?

Comment: No, json_encode is correct, as I have an object passed from my controller to twig, which needs to be encoded to JSON in order to be used by the javascript.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46868244/4325011) could work for you or at leat give you a hint

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to {{ dump(qualifications) }}? What is the  output?

Comment: As mentioned in my original post, dump does not work. {{dump()}} and {{dump(qualifications)}} just loads for a while and then results in an unspecified server 500 error with a blank screen.

Comment: Take a look At log files, both symfony logs and php log, and post the content